# python make a function calling the name to get the id #

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry new to python, was trying to make a func when I say getID('foo'), it'll return me the id #.

```
info = {1:   {'desc': 'one',    'length': 1, 'id': 1,    'weight': '4',  'name': 'foo'}, 
       506:  {'desc': 'two',    'length': 2, 'id': 506,  'weight': '32', 'name': 'bar'}, 
       1156: {'desc': 'Three.', 'length': 3, 'id': 1156, 'weight': '64', 'name': 'too'}}
```

This is what I have but it doesn't get me what I wanted. Any help would be great thanks

```
def GetID(name):

    for v in info.values():
        for k in v.keys():
            if k == name:
                return(v[id])
            else:
                return "wrong name"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the right data structure would make this a lot easier—and, assuming you're calling `GetID` more than a handful of times, also a lot faster. (In general, when you find it too complicated to extract the information you want from your data, the answer is usually to change the data structure.)

If you had a dictionary that mapped each `name` to the `id`, you could just do this:

```
def GetID(name):
    return name_to_id.get(name, "wrong name")
```

If you've never seen the `d.get(key, default)` before, it's equivalent to `d[key]`, except that if the key isn't present, you get `default` instead of raising a `KeyError`.

---

So, how do you build that dictionary? Well, you already know how to iterate over your existing dictionary explicitly, so let's do it that way:

```
name_to_id = {}
for v in info.values():
    name_to_id[v['name']] = v['id']
```

If you want to make it more concise:

```
name_to_id = {v['name']: v['id'] for v in info.values()}
```

Either way, you're just looping over the dictionary one time, to set up the `name_to_id` mapping, instead of every time you need to look up a name. And it's a simpler loop.

And it means that each name lookup is now incredibly simple and incredibly fast.

Answer (score 1):

1. `ie_info` does not match global variable `info`.
2. Quote `id`: `v['id']`

   - without quote, `id` references [`id` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).
3. You don't need to iterate all dictionary entries to check `name` key, value.

   - Just use `dict['name']`, `dict['id']`

---

```
>>> info = {1:   {'desc': 'one',    'length': 1, 'id': 1,    'weight': '4',  'name': 'foo'},
...        506:  {'desc': 'two',    'length': 2, 'id': 506,  'weight': '32', 'name': 'bar'},
...        1156: {'desc': 'Three.', 'length': 3, 'id': 1156, 'weight': '64', 'name': 'too'}}
>>>
>>>
>>> def GetID(name):
...     for v in info.values():
...         if v['name'] == name:
...             return(v['id'])
...     return 'wrong name'
...
>>> GetID('foo')
1
>>> GetID('who')
'wrong name'
```

Comment: This nicely explains everything that makes the OP's code fail, except that `name` has the same problem as `id`, and you apparently fixed it without noticing or mentioning it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def GetID(name):

    for v in info.values(): # your variable is called info not ie_info
        for k in v.keys():
            if k == 'name':
                return(v['id']) # you were missing the quotes around id
            else:
                return "wrong name"
```

Comment: You also need to quote `'name'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def GetID(name):
    return [x['id'] for x in info.values() if x['name'] == name]
```

that's how you're not looping on all keys but take only the one you want

Comment: Technicalkly, Python's doing the looping for you. It will also return a list not an object

Comment: right, I was referring the second (inner loop) that has to be avoided

Answer (score 0):

I'd call `next` on a generator that yields what you want; you can specify a "default" value if the generator is exhausted without yielding a result:

```
next((i for i,d in info.items() if d['name'] == 'foo'), 'wrong name')
Out[22]: 1

next((i for i,d in info.items() if d['name'] == 'baz'), 'wrong name')
Out[23]: 'wrong name'
```

(using python 3 syntax here, use `iteritems` instead of `items` in python 2)

Comment: I this would be a lot clearer to a novice as two lines that one—create the genexpr, then `next` it. Also, you're returning the key that the subdict is stored under, but the OP wants the `id` value of the subject. They happen to be the same in his example, but who knows if we can rely on that?

Comment: Yeah being a bit lazy here.  I didn't really look at his data structure, it really needs some work.